# Notepad++ Find Certain Character Between Start of line and String

Tags: notepad++

Basically as the title says. I want to find "," character between the start of each new line and ".nes"

```
Europe\California, Games (E) [!].nes,131088,8709c41e,
```

I want to be able to select any commas between the start of the line and ".nes". As you see there is one in the example.
I've been looking around here and other placed but the closest i've gotten is with

```
^.*.nes
```

But that only selects all the text from the start of the line to just before .nes. What do I need to add for it to select just the comma? Every edit I do to the line results in nothing found.

Comment: Do you just want to **match** commas or do you want to **replace** them with something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will remove all commas between beginning of line and `.nes`, there can be **any** number of them.

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^|\G(?!^))[^,]*\K,(?=.*?\.nes)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # non capture grorup
    ^           # beginning of line
  |           # OR
    \G          # restart from last match position
    (?!^)       # negative lookahead, make sure we are not at the beginning of a line
)           # end group
[^,]*       # 0 or more any character that is not a comma
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
,           # a comma
(?=         # positive lookahead, make sure we have ".nes" after in the line
    .*?         # 0 or more any character but newline
    \.nes       # literally .nes
)           # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Wow this is an even more in depth explanation. Really good! The 'explanation' section is very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regular expression that finds lines with your specification:

```
^.*,.*\.nes
```

I saw two problems with your suggested regular expression:

1. The dot before nes needs to be masked with a "\" to prevent it being interpreted as the any character wildcard.
2. The comma was missing from your expression.

In Notepad++, there is no way to just select the "," when the pattern matches, but you can replace it with something using Search and replace. For example, to replace it with a "+", use this:

Search for

```
^(.*),(.*\.nes)
```

Replace with

```
^$1+$2
```

The $1 refers to the first group: all characters from the start of the line to just before the ",".

Comment: Thanks great explanation! I ended up using the last bit there with $1$2 and it removed the comma.